# URL rewrite and domain frame

Tags: domains, url, url-rewriting

I have registered the domain www.posti.sh at nic.sh. The website is on the server www.myskoob.com/postish. Unfortunately, nic.sh does not support frames, i.e. that the domain stays posti.sh as it forwards to www.myskoob.com/postish - so I thought about a URL rewrite on the server.

Unfortunately I have no idea how rewriting works - I am thankful for explanations - but I would also like to ask whether this is generally possible. What I need is:

- The server needs to recognize that the folder postish is accessed
- Depending on the file that is opened, it needs to rewrite the url to www.posti.sh/<-according filename here->
- Also, the server needs to understand that a link to www.posti.sh/about.php links to www.myskoob.com/postish/about.php and likewise for other files - at the moment, when I type in posti.sh/about.php it redirects to http://www.myskoob.com/postishabout.php, which does not exist
- All this should be possible irrespective of whether the url contains a "www" at the beginning or not
- A plus but not necessary would be that it does not display the .php extensions

Would that generally be possible? If not, what would be the alternatives? If anyone knows how to do it, any code and/or way to do it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't host the website on the posti.sh server normally?

Comment: I only registered a domain, it was no combined package

Comment: Can you not point the nameservers for the domain to your existing shared hosting and use it as an addon domain?

Comment: Sorry I am afraid I do not understand what that means! Could you elaborate further?

Comment: Normally the company you host you website with will provide you with nameservers, you then go to your domain registrar and add those as the domain's nameservers. You then go back to your host and add the domain and point that at a website. What company do you host your website with?

Comment: I can provide free hosting to you (assuming it's not the next Facebook) and help you set this up until you find a more permanent solution. This would ONLY be temporary, but I'm more than willing to help you set this up for yourself. Email `webmaster at ionfish dot org`.

Answer (score 1):

Point the DNS to your existing domain (as per toomanyairmiles suggestion in comments of original post) - here is a guide on the Go Daddy website, but the principal is the same.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names